# Vagrant thowing the error `playbook` does not exist on the guest

Tags: ansible, vagrant, virtual-machine

I end up with the below error when I do vagrant up.

```
`playbook` does not exist on the guest: /vagrant/.c7/provision/playbook.yml
```

I removed .c7 folder when I am cleaning up vagrant and after reinstall, it looks like those folders are not created again. Hence the error.

How can I tell/do to vagrant that create everything again including those configurations. Reinstalling not helping.

Tried destroy and up again. No luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not clear on how you are provisioning the guest.
Try

```
 vagrant up --provision
```

if that doesn't help, then , halt/destroy the guest,  try removing the box and start all over again.

```
vagrant box remove NAME
vagrant up
```